# Next App can reach a file while in localhost but not in production

Tags: next.js, vercel, mdxjs

I am trying to build a page that reads some content mdx files inside the `src/bounties/content/bounties` folder, and my app can make it work while in localhost.
But, everytime I upload and host it in Vercel or in Netlify, it gives me the `ENOET` error.

This is the `page.tsx` file, where the directory is called and the mdx file is rendered with `next-mdx-remote`

```
import { type MDXRemoteSerializeResult } from "next-mdx-remote";
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";
import { MdxContent } from "../../mdx-content";
import BountiesBreadcrumb from "@/app/components/bountiesBreadcrumb";
import path from "path";

type Frontmatter = {
  title: string;
  date: string;
};

type Post<TFrontmatter> = {
  serialized: MDXRemoteSerializeResult;
  frontmatter: TFrontmatter;
};

interface IBountyProps {
  params: {
    slug: string;
  };
}

async function getPost(filepath: string): Promise<Post<Frontmatter>> {
  const raw = await fs.readFile(filepath, "utf-8");

  const serialized = await serialize(raw, {
    parseFrontmatter: true,
  });

  const frontmatter = serialized.frontmatter as Frontmatter;

  return {
    frontmatter,
    serialized,
  };
}

export default async function Bounty({ params }: IBountyProps) {
  const filePath = path.join(
    "src",
    "app",
    "bounties",
    "content",
    "bounties",
    `${params.slug}.mdx`
  );

  const { serialized, frontmatter } = await getPost(filePath);

  return (
    <div className="text-zinc-400 p-16 border-r border-zinc-800">
      <BountiesBreadcrumb />

      <div className="py-16 max-w-4xl">
        <h1 className="text-zinc-300 font-bold text-4xl">
          {frontmatter.title}
        </h1>

        <span className="text-zinc-400 text-md mt-8">
          Published at {frontmatter.date}
        </span>

        <div className="mt-8">
          <MdxContent source={serialized} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For example, when the user reaches the route `/bounties/dynamic-sidebar`, this page needs to read the file: `src/app/bounties/content/bounties/dynamic-sidebar.mdx` and then render it into the page layout.

There's the error message:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'src/app/bounties/content/bounties/dynamic-sidebar.mdx'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'src/app/bounties/content/bounties/dynamic-sidebar.mdx'
}
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'src/app/bounties/content/bounties/dynamic-sidebar.mdx'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'src/app/bounties/content/bounties/dynamic-sidebar.mdx'
}
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
  digest: '3395753351'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing probably has to do with the way you are generating the file path to search for. Try the following example instead, this should work:

```js
const workDirPath = process.cwd(); 
const contentPath = "src/app/bounties/content/bounties";
const filePath = path.join(workDirPath, contentPath, `${params.slug}.mdx`);
```

As you see I use the `process.cwd` function in the above example, this ensures that you are pointing to your project root and only then joining your relative path to it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this works flawlessly in my project running on Vercel